# How to stop a callback method in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var watcher = chokidar.watch('folder-name');
var log = console.log.bind(console);
watcher
    .on('add', path => log(`File ${path} has been added`));`
```

It should show the output when I add new files into the folder, and I want to stop it, when I add maximum of two files. Then I want to print those file names separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Stop watching.
watcher.close();
```

[doc](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: No, I want to add 2 new files into the folder , after that it should stop automatically.

Comment: and i want to print name of the file separately  which could be added by me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19470528)

Comment: @pradeep essential part is included, link is only here for reference.